# Why is my log-in screen such a mess?

Tags: 13.10, login-screen, desktop-background

Samsung Series 9 - 13.10

Every time I boot up and get to the login screen, I get to this mess of graywashed icons and background. As you can see, due to terrible HDMI support, the background does show up right, but everything that gets mirrored is a mess. Additionally the mouse does not show up. Any thoughts on how I could fix this?

[image]

Comment: Has it always been like this? Do you experience this if you unplug your HDMI? What video card do you have and what drivers did you install? please provide more information.

Comment: No, it has been doing this after the last mass update a few weeks ago. This happens always. HDMI used to give me an extended display, now it just mirrors. As you can see on the right the laptop is all grayed out. That's what it looks like w/ or w/o the HDMI. I have no idea what video drivers I have. Could you tell me how to look that up? I believe the that laptop has intelgraphics 400 or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a screwup caused by XFCE, Gnome and KDE all being installed on my machine. I removed/uninstalled/purged all three and now I do not have any issues!